# Validation fails in tinyMCE editor

Tags: laravel, tinymce, validate.js

I am trying to implement Jquery Validate.js in my Create n Edit page.
Validation works fine in my create page but when it comes to edit page the real problem arises. If i try to check title field first for validation then the validation works but if i try to validate my  Textarea first that has intregrated TinyMCe then the Jquery Validation  does not work. The rules for Validation is same for create n edit page.

Comment: This the link to my codes https://codeshare.io/y3sQT

Comment: Please do not use and external tool, use the code snippet option included in message editor